# Link to Outlook.com that prepopulates the account field leaving only the password to be entered to log in

Tags: outlook.com

Is there a link to Outlook.com that it contains the email account in it?

I want to click on the link and have the email address prepopulated at Outlook.com so I just need to enter my password to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If the email address is `johnsmith@outlook.com`, you can use the following URL:

```
https://outlook.office.com/mail/?login_hint=johnsmith%40outlook.com
```